# Validating String in object

Tags: javascript

I have following object:

```
var obj = {
 "id": 1,
 "name": "john",
 "creds": {
   "username": "abc@yopmail.com"   
 },
 "account": {
  "credit": {
   "number": "123456"
  },
  "name": "accountName"
 }
}
```

How can i dynamically get value:

I want to get the value by passing the hierarchy as string

```
console.log("Username: ", obj["creds.username"]);
console.log("CreditNumber: ", obj["account.credit.number"]);
```

Note: the object might have nth deep child objects

Please advise me a dynamic solution for this

Comment: i can't understand your question. You want a sort of for loop that gives you creds.username?

Comment: @Luxor001: I want to get the value by passing json hierarchy as string.

Comment: https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath

Comment: myJson[Creds][username], where Creds = "creds" and username="username"

Comment: You are not using JSON in your code. This is a JavaScript object. JSON is a string representation of an object, array or value. 

You can get the values from the object using the following:

    console.log("Username: ", myJson["creds"]["username"]);
    console.log("CreditNumber: ", myJson["account"]["credit"]["number"]);

Or even simpler:

    console.log("Username: ", myJson.creds.username);
    console.log("CreditNumber: ", myJson.account.credit.number);

Comment: @Quentin: Thanks man, duplicate marked answer solved my query. Thanks all.

Comment: `function getProp(obj, prop) {
      return prop.split('.').reduce(function(o, k) {
        return o && o[k];
      }, obj);
    }; getProp(obj, "account.credit.number")`

Comment: you can ues a function to do this,like this function:`function demo(str){
        var result = myJson;
        var arr = str.split("\.");
        for(var i= 0,item;item=arr[i++];){
            result = result[item];
        }
        return result;
    }`   and use this function like this:`demo("creds.username")`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get the value by `[]` use key as string like, `['account']` or you can use native way `obj.key.childKey`.

```
console.log("Username: ", myJson.creds.username);
console.log("CreditNumber: ", myJson.account.credit.number);
```

or

```
console.log("Username: ", myJson['crews']['username']);
console.log("CreditNumber: ", myJson['account']['credit']['number']);
```

Comment: This is the answer and the way you should go "dynamically" trought an object

Comment: I cannot use array notation, the hierarchy could go very deep.

Comment: Ok. You can go with first type. There is another reason for using array notation.

Answer (score 1):

Simply by accessing the value with the dot notation:

```
console.log("Username: ", myJson.creds.username);
console.log("CreditNumber: ", myJson.account.credit.number);
```